# Hashtable - Get the 1st element before index

Tags: java, datatable

I have this hashtable :

```
private final Hashtable<Integer,Character> htable = new Hashtable<>();
```

I am storing some element in the table with indexes that may reach high ranges.
Then when i want to get an item, if it does not exist, i would like the get the first existing one before.

A naive way to do it could be :

```
int index = given_index;
while(htable.get(index) == null && index >= 0)
    index --;
```

Doing this may compute a big amount of values.
Is there a better strategy, or maybe another sort of table allowing to compute less ?

Comment: Do you have a lot of get from this hashtable? Have you looked at a sorted list instead?

Comment: I would check [NavigableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) *"A SortedMap extended with navigation methods returning the closest matches for given search targets....methods lowerKey(K), floorKey(K), ceilingKey(K), and higherKey(K)..."*

Comment: I may not have a lot of values but the keys may reach high values

Comment: The ``NavigableMap`` with the ``floorEntry()`` method looks right. I will try. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NavigableMap (as mentioned in comment by user15358848)

Ref: [NavigableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html)

Generally, implementations should not support `null` values. If there are implementations that supports `null`, it will be impossible to check whether the response `null` was due to absence or an actual value.

#### lowerEntry

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key strictly less than the given key, or null if there is no such key.

1. `get` value for key
2. if fetched value is `null`, then fetch `lowerEntry`
3. `getOrDefault(key, navigableMap.lowerEntry(index))` will be costly if actual key is present mostly due to additional `navigableMap.lowerEntry` call

```java
  Character value = navigableMap.get(index);
  if (value == null) {
    value = navigableMap.lowerEntry(index);
  }
  return value;
```

#### floorEntry

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key less than or equal to the given key, or null if there is no such key.

1. read using `floorEntry`
2. if non-null entry, return value
3. else return `null`

```java
  Map.Entry<Integer,​ Character> entry = navigableMap.floorEntry(index);
  return null != entry ? entry.getValue() : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

*get the index or the index in front of it with a lambda*

```
htable.keySet().stream().sorted()
  .filter(i -> i <= target).max(Integer::compare).orElse(-1);
```

… where `target` is the index You are searching